# How to detect curve shaped clusters in 2D array? Python

Tags: cluster-analysis, curve

What is the smartest way to detect curves in a 2d dataset? There must be a way to cluster data points by defining maximum distance to neighbor. My goal is to apply polyfit function over each curve and use this template for alike datasets.

Example of data:

array([[   0.,    0.,    0., ..., 2020., 2020., 2020.],
       [  51.,   76.,  194., ..., 1862., 1915., 2021.]])

[image]

Figured out this can be done with Agglomerative Clustering, here's the code and result:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

#Reshape data

a = array[:, 0].flatten()
b = array[:, 1].flatten()

array_new = np.matrix([a,b])
array_new = np.squeeze(np.asarray(array_new))

array_new1 = array_new.T

#Clustering algorithm

n_clusters = None
model = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters,
                                affinity='euclidean', 
                                linkage='single',
                                compute_full_tree=True,
                                distance_threshold=15) 
model.fit(array_new1)
labels = model.labels_
n_clusters = len(list(set(labels)))
print(n_clusters)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, n_clusters)]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
for i, color in enumerate(colors, start=1):
    plt.scatter(array_new1[labels==i,0], array_new1[labels==i,1], color=color)
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()

![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utwqP.png)

#plotting result

data = pd.DataFrame({'x' : array_new1[:,0],
                     'y' : array_new1[:,1],
                     'label' : labels})

data.sort_values(by='label')

counter = 0
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.scatter(5*array[:, 0], array[:, 1])
for i in range(n_clusters):

    if len(data.loc[data['label'] == i].iloc[:,0]) > 50 \
    and len(data.loc[data['label'] == i].iloc[:,0]) < 1000:

            counter += 1

            z = np.polyfit(data.loc[data['label'] == i].iloc[:,0], 
                            data.loc[data['label'] == i].iloc[:,1],
                              2)

            p = np.poly1d(z)
            xp = np.linspace(0, tasku_sk, 50)

            #plt.scatter(data.loc[data['label'] == i].iloc[:,0], 
            #            data.loc[data['label'] == i].iloc[:,1])
            plt.plot(5*xp, p(xp), c='r', lw=4)

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()

print(counter)

![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQHOf.png)

22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The supposedly oldest of all clustering algorithms: single-link.